# Invoking json web services in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am currently trying to use the Liferay JSON WebService API to access entities (e.g. "Student") from my database. I used ServiceBuilder to build Services for this entity and implemented a method "public Student getStudentByID(long StudentId){...}" in the StudentServiceImpl.
I am also able to see and access this method via "http://sampletest.com/RestTestLiferayProject-portlet/api/jsonws" 
How can i invoke this service from another portlet?

Answer (score 2):

my understanding is the json services are intended for use from outside your Liferay instance.  From within a portlet you should be able to import your service classes and use them directly.

Apologies if I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: I am talking about creating web service client. anyway i followed http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/writing-the-remote-service-class-liferay-portal-6-1-dev-guide-en     this link to create my json ws. here  the wsdl http://localhost:8080/event-listing-portlet/api/axis/Plugin_Event_EventService?wsdl
. but i can't get the wsdl in mycase